# Changing one dictionary at two different events leads to KeyError in some cases (because of timing of key event + event due to dt)

Tags: python, dictionary, pygame, mutable

Copy of the final question at the bottom:
"I have no idea how to solve this bug. One action is time dependent and the other one is player input dependent. Someone with an idea? Is there something in python working with mutable data which handles cases where one object gets changed at different times from different places?"

I code my own Tetris in Pygame. At the moment my goal is to rebuild the game mode "Survival" from here: https://jstris.jezevec10.com/?play=4
The player needs to survive as long as possible while every 1 second a new line with only 1 free spot will be added at the bottom and shifts the game field towards the top.

My problem is, there is a key.event where the player drops a piece and clears a row with that action and on the other hand there is time event where every one second a line is randomly added to the field. Both events change values in a dictionary. In general this code works but there is very small window of time where dependent on the actions the code throws an error.

Short explanation of my game:
There is a grid ( list of lists 10x20 ) where each element is a RGB color (0,0,0) starting everytime with black and will be filled with information (colors) of the current falling piece or the field at the bottom where pieces are locked. The grid will be drawn every frame. Pieces which are already placed are stored in a dictionary. The grid requests the dict for the locked pieces every time before drawing.

[image: screenshot of the original game.]

In this picture you see the original game. At that moment 6 lines already are added to the field.
Every line will be generated at the bottom of the field with the grey colour with one free random spot. Everytime a line will be generated the information is added in my "locked" dictionary ( key = (x,y) : value = (153,153,153) ) and a function changes the y value in every key by 1 to the top.
At the same time if the player clears a row (in this picture it would be the 6th row counting from the bottom) there is a function which deletes this cleared row in the "locked" dict and changes all y values which are greater than that line by 1 to the bottom.

Here are the two functions:

```
def clear_rows(grid, locked): # (0,0) is at the top left, x increases right, y increases down

    
    i = len(grid) - 1  # last row
    rows_cleared = 0
    while i > -1:
        row = grid[i]

        if BLACK not in row: #which means the row is full and can be cleared
            i_new = i + rows_cleared
            for j in range(len(row)):
                del locked[(j, i_new)]
            rows_cleared += 1

            for key in sorted(list(locked), key=lambda x: x[1])[::-1]:
                x_coord, y_coord = key
                if y_coord < i_new:
                    new_key = (x_coord, y_coord + 1)
                    locked[new_key] = locked.pop(key)
            i -= 1
        else:
            i -= 1

    return rows_cleared
```

and

```
def survival_add_line(locked):
    for key in sorted(list(locked)):
        x, y = key
        new_key = (x, y - 1)
        locked[new_key] = locked.pop(key)

    gap = random.randint(0,9)
    for i in range(10):
        if not i == gap:
            locked[(i, 19)] = SURVIVAL_GRAY
```

This is the code in my mainloop:

```
if level_time / 1000 >= 1:
            survival_add_line(locked)
            level_time = 0
if change_piece:
    for pos in tetrimino_position:
        locked[(pos[0], pos[1])] = current_piece.color      
    current_piece = next_pieces[0]
    next_pieces.pop(0)
    next_pieces.append(new_tetromino())
    change_piece = False
    cleared_lines += clear_rows(grid, locked)
```

I noticed the bug can only happen at the very bottom of the field. If I understand it right it happens when the player drops a piece in that exact moment when survival_add_line() is already called but before if change_piece.
Survival_add_line() shifts every line one to the top, then the clear_row function wants to delete the last row (which is now the second last) and it can't find the key in the last row to delete --> KeyError.

I have no idea how to solve this bug. One action is time dependent and the other one is player input dependent.
Someone with an idea?
Is there something in python working with mutable data which handles cases where one object gets changed at different times from different places?

Comment: What about: if change_piece: blah blah elif level_time / 1000 >= 1: blah blah

Comment: but then it would be an either...or thing which is not right, woudn't it ? Both blocks are independent. The player can drop a piece at every point and the other way round after 1 sec one lines will be added, whether change piece or not.

Comment: Yes I understand what you mean. What happens if you swap the if statements around so you're testing for change_pieces first and level_time second?

Comment: I had it first in that order. I won't get an error then but my field get messed up with colors/black/grey. same problem only in the other direction. the dictionary will get wrong information about coordinates and its colors

Comment: but your first answer is maybe a way to go. I tried it with elif like 50 times and wasn't able to get the error situation. If I do it that way, all that happens is if the time is >1000, I skip the change piece part for 1 frame and in the next one it will get detected . The code is running at 60fps, so that shouldn't have impact on the game speed right?

Comment: That's what I was thinking. Unless the player can drop to the bottom row 1 frame after the last drop then you should be ok with that.

Comment: yes, I think that's it. I double checked, the bool change_piece which becomes true when the piece hits the ground won't change to False again till the line if change_piece: is executed. So in one frame the if statement with time is true and add a line, in the next frame the other block will be executed. the worlds fastest tetris player are able to drop 7 pieces per second...I guess still not enough for 1 frame back to back :D Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling both statements with if, an if/elif block gets the job done! (change_piece can now be delayed by 1 frame, but that's not noticeable for the player)

<sub>*Posted on behalf of the question asker*</sub>